# Que disent les francais quand ils sont photographiés ?

Tags: société, demande-de-mot

En anglais, les photographes disent : « Say “cheese”! » (Dites « fromage »), mais « fromage » ne semble pas être employé dans une situation comme ça.

Que disent les français ?

Comment: J'ai souvent entendu : "Ouistiti!" avec un dernier *i* qui n'en finit pas.

Comment: Ca doit dépendre des régions : je n'ai jamais entendu cette expression. J'ai parfois entendu un sobre "Souriez !", ou "On sourit !". Enfin pour avoir l'attention des enfants il y a le classique "Le petit oiseau va sortir !".

Comment: Lors de la campagne électorale Jacques Chirac utilisait "Ouistiti se." : http://books.google.fr/books?id=W6NQtgLi6WMC&pg=PT546&lpg=PT546&dq=ouistiti+sex+Chirac&source=bl&ots=U2uoCQy8_J&sig=QhIgszVeYPYrxYVEgiRJn7mtUP8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0r53Uq2hAoTQ0QXG24C4Dw&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=ouistiti%20sex%20Chirac&f=false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les français ont de l'imagination et trouvent une blague drôle. OK, souvent ils n'en ont pas. Donc certains disent « [ouistiti](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ouistiti) ! », et d'autres disent « *cheese* ! »…

*Ouistiti*, qui est prononcé `/wistiti/`, serait [le secret pour un sourire parfait](http://blog.iamnikon.com/en_GB/coolpix/the-secret-to-a-perfect-photo-smile-not-%E2%80%98say-cheese%E2%80%99-but%E2%80%A6-%E2%80%98ouistiti%E2%80%99/)…

Comment: Je ne vais pas ajouter une réponse répétitive qui n'aurait qu'un détail de différent : chez les enfants, le mot « cerise » est très prisé.

Answer (score 2):

On conseille en général "ouistiti" - mais les Français savent prononcer du moins approximativement et c'est bien suffisant pour paraître sourire : "cheese".

Answer (score 1):

Habituellement, on dit tout simplement : "Souriez !" 
:-)
Sinon, oui, c'est vrai on entend assez souvent  "Cheese".
"Ouistiti" vient plutôt pour tenter un trait d'humour.